# Wordpress Theme Customizer: Live Preview CSS by Media Query

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm using Worpress' [Theme Customization API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API) to allow changes by a user to my website colors. My website is responsive and the navigation changes color for mobile devices. My CSS looks similar to the following:

```
nav { background-color: #fff; }

@media only screen and max-width 767px {
    nav { background-color: #b00; }
}
```

I set up all of the JavaScript for the live preview as follows, but this binds to all display sizes. I'm not able to figure out how to make this bind to a media query.

```
wp.customize( 'background_color', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( newval ) {
        $('nav').css('background-color', newval );
    } );
} );
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: An if statement based around this could work... `$(window).width() < 768`

Comment: @andrew Thanks! That worked perfectly. Updated to...
`
if ($(window).width() < 768)
  {
 wp.customize( 'background_color', function( value ) {
     value.bind( function( newval ) {
         $('nav').css('background-color', newval );
     } );
 } );
}
`
Now I just have to figure out how to make it work if I start larger and resize. I attempted...
`
$(window).resize(function() {
 if ($(window).width() < 768)
MORE...
`
..but then it doesn't work UNLESS I resize the browser. *sigh*

Comment: Glad to help... Use `$(window).trigger('resize');` and load it on `$(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).trigger('resize');
   
  });`

Answer (score 0):

Your media query in CSS should be:

`@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)` <-- brackets and colon missing here.

[Further Info here.](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: The media query works fine. It's the JavaScript that's the issue. @AndrewHaining found the solution. Thanks.